# How to split string into parts and join each part with another table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have two separate tables in my database where I have a table **cases** in which i have a column as *connected_advocates* and I am storing value in that column as string like this, 2,13,4 each value in that is id of another table Advocates. So now I wants to get name of every connected advocates by splitting ids from that string and join each of that with advocates table

```
Cases table
+-----------+----------------------+-----------+
+ casecode  + connected_advocates  + status    +
+-----------+----------------------+-----------+
+ 101       + 1,13,4               + active    +
+-----------+----------------------+-----------+
+ 102       + 9,4                + active    +
+-----------+----------------------+-----------+



Advocate Table 
+--------------+----------------------+-----------+
+ advocate_id  + advocate_name        + status    +
+--------------+----------------------+-----------+
+ 1            + ali raza             + active    +
+--------------+----------------------+-----------+
+ 13           + suhail ahemd         + active    +
+--------------+----------------------+-----------+
+ 4            + nazeer hussain       + active    +
+--------------+----------------------+-----------+


Now I want result something like this,
+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+ case_code    + connected_advocate_names                    +
+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+ 101          + ali raza,suhail ahemd,nazeer hussain        +
+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I tried many method but none of them work for me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET` could work.

```
SELECT a.casecode, GROUP_CONCAT(b.advocate_name)
FROM cases a
JOIN advocate b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.advocate_id, a.connected_advocates)
GROUP BY a.casecode
```